# want to delete data from two tables using one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Question:

There are two tables named as “EMPLOYEE” & “SALARY” having following fields:

```
EMPLOYEE: 
ID (int), 
EmployeeCode (varchar(50)), 
Name (varchar(50)), 
City (varchar(50))

SALARY: 
EmployeeCode (varchar(50)), 
Amount(int)
```

Delete all employee and their salary who are from “DELHI”.
i want to delete both tables together in one query.

Solution:

```
DELETE Employee, Salary FROM Employee e
JOIN Salary s ON s.EmployeeCode= e.EmployeeCode
WHERE  City ='Delhi';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to delete from two tables at the same time, this should work

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE s FROM Salary s
JOIN Employee e ON s.EmployeeCode= e.EmployeeCode
WHERE  e.City ='Delhi';

DELETE e FROM Employee e
WHERE  e.City ='Delhi';

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE e 
FROM Employee e 
    JOIN Salary s ON (s.EmployeeCode= e.EmployeeCode) 
WHERE City ='Delhi';

DELETE s 
FROM Salary s LEFT JOIN Employee e 
    ON (s.EmployeeCode= e.EmployeeCode AND e.City ='Delhi') 
WHERE e.EmployeeCode IS NULL
```

Comment: You forgot to delete the salary data as well.

Comment: will it delete the salary data also?

Comment: Script appended for Salary Delete

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.